# $addToset do not work in update if record not exists

Tags: mongodb, update

I am trying to use following query

```
db.TestColl.update({ "tags" : "silk" , "host" : "host.com"},{ "$set" : { "cat" : "MOVIE" , "$addToSet" : { "articleId" : { "$each" : [ "20442242"]}} , "publishTime" : 1370427540000} , "$inc" : { "count" : 1}},true,false);
```

The reason is if a record exists and a new article id comes it will be added to the set and count will be updated but if the record does not exists then it should store a record. But it gives me an error that while storage `$addtoSet` and `$each` are not valid modifier.

Comment: $addToSet should be at the same level as $set , not inside of it

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue. I made an error in the update statement. The correct version is:

```
db.TestColl.update({
    "tags" : "silk" ,
    "host" : "host.com"
  }, {
    "$set" : { "cat" : "MOVIE", "publishTime" : 1370427540000 },
    "$addToSet" : {
      "articleId" : { "$each" : [ "20442242" ]}} ,
      "$inc" : { "count" : 1}
  },
  true, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

If document does not exists `$addToSet` will fail. When you initialize the document you need to use $push which creates the table and then `$addToSet` will work.

I can't reproduce the error.

```
mongos> db.test.update({name:"antonis"},{"$set" : { "cat" : "MOVIE","publishTime" : 1370427540000 }, "$addToSet" : { "articleId" : { "$each" : [ "20442242"]}} , "$inc" : { "count" : 1}},true,false)

mongos> db.test.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("548193318a8c8d4e5c10e90c"), "articleId" : [  "20442242" ], "cat" : "MOVIE", "count" : 1, "name" : "antonis", "publishTime" : 1370427540000 }


mongos> db.test.update({name:"antonis1"},{"$set" : { "cat" : "MOVIE","publishTime" : 1370427540000 }, "$addToSet" : { "articleId" : { "$each" : [ "20442242"]}} , "$inc" : { "count" : 1}},true,false)


mongos> db.test.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("548193318a8c8d4e5c10e90c"), "articleId" : [  "20442242" ], "cat" : "MOVIE", "count" : 1, "name" : "antonis", "publishTime" : 1370427540000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5481934e8a8c8d4e5c10e90d"), "articleId" : [  "20442242" ], "cat" : "MOVIE", "count" : 1, "name" : "antonis1", "publishTime" : 1370427540000 }
```

Comment: i resolved the issue i made error in update statement correct version was also updated in the question